# Does FileWriter.flush() always start a new line?

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I want to write something to a file through FileWriter, like this:

```
if(<condition>)
{
   writer.write(term);
   writer.flush();
}
writer.close();
```

But that will always append an empty line at the end of my file. May I ask how to get rid of this empty line?

Comment: `flush` isn't appending an empty line.

Comment: Neither `flush()` or `close()` changes the open file. Have you double checked the content you're writing?

Comment: What software are you using to look at your file?  Or in other words, are you sure there's really an empty line there?

Comment: `flush` potentially does change the file because it writes any buffered information into the file that was held only in memory. Because `close` calls `flush`, it, too, potentially changes the open file.

Answer (score 0):

flush(),close() none of these method will add empty line. So please check your input stream/string.